# json: how to get the json-string into a javascript object

Tags: javascript, xml, json

i am converting my ajax code from xml to json, but i am missing something basic here:

when i receive the json-string on the client-side, what is the recommended way to convert it into a javascript object.

for example i get this string:

```
{"connectionid":12345}
```

and i would like to do something like this:

```
alert(xmlhttp.responseText.connectionid);
```

thanks!

Comment: you could use the evil eval :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`JSON.parse()`](http://www.json.org/js.html), or `eval()`, if you like to live dangerously (or fully trust where your JSON comes from).

If you happen to be using jQuery, you get [`$.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers (the recent ones at least.. not IE7) have a native JSON object that you can use to parse and stringify JSON.

```
alert(JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText).connectionid);
```

In browsers that don't support the JSON object, you can either use a JSON parser from [JSON.org](http://www.json.org) or use eval(), however eval() is quite dangerous and i definitly don't advise you to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Call eval on the response text.

```
var response = eval(xmlHttp.responseText);
alert(response.connectionId);
```

Comment: I think it's a bit rough to mark it down. Unless you are going to rely on a third party library, which was not specified in the original question, then eval is an acceptable solution, if you are in control of the source, which I am assuming you are for XmlHttpRequests.

Answer (score 0):

you could use eval
check this out : http://www.json.org/js.html

edit - oops, others typed faster :(